# Why the emit of an event is not working with vue, while the logic is completed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to emit `onClick` event to the app component, but clicking on Next and Previous buttons isn't working. Even though I'm handling the events in the `Step1` child component. I wonder why could this happen ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jasper-teh1im?file=/src/components/Step1.vue

```js
<template >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <h1>Step 1</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label
        ><input
          name="name"
          v-model="firstName"
          placeholder="Your first name"
          class="form-control"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label
        ><input
          name="lastname"
          v-model="lastName"
          placeholder="Your last name"
          class="form-control"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <button type="button" @click.prevent="nextStep" class="btn">
        Next step
      </button>
    </div>
    <Button firstName="firstName" lastName="lastName" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Button from "./Button.vue";
export default {
  inject: ["firstName", "lastName"],
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Button,
  },
  methods: {
    nextStep() {
      this.$emit("next");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Here is the fixed playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-http-lu9ikg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emit events are only passed to the direct parent not the grand parent component, in this case try to provide the event as you did with firstName and lastName :

App.vue :

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
   ....
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      firstName: this.user_detail1.firstName,
      lastName: this.user_detail1.lastName,
      paymentAmount: this.user_detail2.paymentAmount,
      accountNumber: this.user_detail2.accountNumber,
      next: this.nextStep,
      previous: this.previousStep
    };
  },
  components: {
    ....
  },
  methods: {
    isFinalStep() {
      this.finalStep = true;
    },
    nextStep() {
      console.log("next");
      this.stepIndex++;
    },
    previousStep() {
      this.stepIndex--;
    },
  },
  computed: {
   ...
  },
};
```

in the step component :

```js
export default {
  inject: ["firstName", "lastName","next","previous"],
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Button,
  },
  methods: {
    nextStep() {
      this.next();
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: @Tolbxela Have tried my suggestion?